# Number of Sylow 3-subgroups of special linear group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I am aware that questions on this topic are around on this site, but they all seem to require information about the group that is not available to me in this problem.

Consider the special linear group $G = SL(2,\mathbb{F_{3}})$, i.e. the group of $2 \times 2$ matrices of determinant $1$ over the field of order $3$, $\mathbb{F_{3}}$.

I want to find the number of Sylow 3-subgroups of $G$.
I have so far shown that $|G|=24$ and that the centraliser of $G$, $Z(G) \neq \{1_{G}\}$. By Sylow's theorem I know that $n_{3} \in \{1,4\}$ as well as $n_{2} \in \{1,3\}$.
Now if I knew how many Sylow 2-subgroups of $G$ there are, I think this problem becomes fairly easy. But I don't have this information and am stuck.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try and use sylow theorems. For example, what are the possibilities for the number of sylow 3-subgroup. It is either $n_{3} =1$ or 4.

Comment: @DanielAkech Right, I have that (Sorry, I've now edited my post), I wasn't sure where to go from there, though.

Comment: If there was a unique Sylow $3$-subgroup then it would be normal. Find an element $x \in G$ of order $3$, then look for some other element $y \in G$ such that $y^{-1}xy$ is not equal to $x$ or to $x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property who says that the number of elementes by order 3 is $n_3(3-1)$.

If $n_3$=1 then you have just 2 elements by order 3. Let consider the next matrices :

$\begin{pmatrix} 
\hat{1} & \hat{1} \\
\hat{0} & \hat{1} 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad,
\begin{pmatrix} 
\hat{1} & \hat{0} \\
\hat{1} & \hat{1} 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad,
\begin{pmatrix} 
\hat{2} & \hat{2} \\
\hat{1} &  \hat{0}
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
$

They are in G and have order 3.
So, $n_3$=4.

Comment: the last matrix of the three you gave is not in G.

Comment: why?Her det is $\hat1$

Comment: Apologies! Misread it.